# Assigning response in Axios

Tags: javascript, variables, promise, axios

Getting a error

This give the expected output

```
.then((response) => {
  console.log(response.data.data) // { object is console logged out here }}
})
```

When I try to assign it to a variable.

```
.then((response) => {
   let data = response.data.data;
})
```

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Comment: Is it possible that `response.data` is updated after this happens? `console.log()` with an object shows **live** data

Comment: if response have data property inside it , it should not give this , try to debug , what you are gettting there ?

Comment: It is a strange one, this is code I have used hundreds of time. Which makes me think maybe the issue is server side. As @Phil said maybe it changes.

Comment: Like `@Atul` said, put a breakpoint on that line and debug it properly. Use your browser's _Network_ console too to inspect the response body

Comment: The two versions are alternatives, yes? You aren't trying to chain them together are you?